# python for one key in list of list, print respective value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list as below:

```
output: [
         '2020-09-24 14:58:24.273000+00:00', 'v1.0.0-rc.2',
          '2019-09-24 14:58:24.273000+00:00', 'v1.3'
        ]
```

I want to print respective second value for `max(output[0])`. Means whichever is youngest in terms for datetime, print second value of it. For the above example, response should be 'v1.0.0-rc.2'

Answer (score 2):

`output[output.index(max(output[::2]))+1]`

since the date is every 2nd item, you do `output[::2]` which returns every 2nd item.

the date is written in a format where you can use string comparison eg: ">" and it will still return the datetime string that is greater than the other, so we can use `max` to get the youngest string

then we need to find the index of that youngest string in the list `output.index`. since the value is the next item after that datetime string, we add 1 to get the index of the value

then we just get the value using that index